# LibGDX get direction of model instance

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

Using the perspective camera you can get it's direction with simply [PerspectiveCamera].direction which returns a Vector 3. Is there any way to get the direction of a model instance?

Answer (score 0):

Check the API: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/Model.html

> A model represents a 3D assets. It stores a hierarchy of nodes. A node
>   has a transform and optionally a graphical part in form of a MeshPart
>   and Material. Mesh parts reference subsets of vertices in one of the
>   meshes of the model. Animations can be applied to nodes, to modify
>   their transform (translation, rotation, scale) over time.

So you could get the direction of a Model by first getting the [Node](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/model/Node.html)'s inside the model and using the Node methods to determine the direction.

For example `myNode.rotation();` will give you a `Quaternion` that you can call the following on `myQuaternion.getPitch();`, `myQuaternion.getYaw();` and `myQuaternion.getRoll();`, this will give you an x, y and z direction. Then you can use the data however you want.